# Can dagger provide different implementations of the interface, depending on requested type?

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

I just started to learn Dagger and I wonder: Can it provide different implementations of the interface, depending on the request?
For example, I have an interface `Api` and I have 2 implementations of this interface - `TwitterApi` and `FacebookApi`. Can I write something like the following?

```
@Provides
Api provideApi(ApiType type) {
    switch (type){
        case TWITTER_API:
            return new TwitterApi();
        case FACEBOOK_API:
            return new FacebookApi();
    }
}
```

Maybe `@Named()` can help somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. You have 2 basic setups, whether you want to access your different implementations at once, or just want to supply one.

### Access them at the same time / within the same scope

This is where you want to use a `@Qualifier`, e.g. `@Named`. It lets you define 2 qualified objects of the same type, so you could request / use both at the same time within the same module.

Here you just put a qualifier on both your implementations, and can provide & request both at the same time.

```
@Binds
@Qualifier("twitter")
Api provideApi(TwitterApi api);
```

And request with

```
@Inject @Qualifier("twitter") Api api;
```

### Use a single one within a scope

In case that you have some `ApiDependentThing` that takes one of your `Api` implementations and you want to either provide `TwitterApi` or `FacebookApi`, you can just bind one of the implementations to your component. You can achieve this by using a `@Component.Builder`, or `@Binds` in a module, or some other way.

With this approach you would not use a qualifier, as you will only have *one* `Api` on your graph that will be used within your component.

E.g. just bind one instance in your builder.

```
@Component
interface ApiComponent {
  Api api();

  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance Builder api(Api api);
    ApiComponent build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can the second behavior be accomplished at run time without having to rebuild the component?